# How to make a single button appear active in android

Tags: java, android

I have been learning java for a little while and am working on an android app.  I am trying to implement a boolean logic for my image buttons nested in a linear layout whereby just one button should show active button while the others are not.
For now each button can toggle between active and inactive but i don't want two ore more buttons showing active at the same time. I want a single one showing an active button at a time.

```
 public void showAudio(View view) {
        if (!audioButtonClicked) {
            audioButtonClicked = true;
            audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_active);
        } else {
            audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_inactive);
            audioButtonClicked = false;
        }

        }

    public void showEvents(View view) {
       if(!eventButtonClicked ) {
eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_active);
           eventButtonClicked = true;
       } else {
           eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
           eventButtonClicked = false;
       }
    }

    public void showMore(View view) {
        if(!moreButtonClicked) {
            moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_active);
            moreButtonClicked = true;

        } else {
            moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
            moreButtonClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change its visibility using button.setVisibility(). This is the pseudo code.

```
if() { // some condition when you want imageButton1 to be visibile and others invisible
    imageButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
    imageButton2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageButton3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else if() { // some other condition when you want imageButton2 to be visibile and others invisible
    imageButton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageButton3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else { // when you want imageButton3 to be visibile and others invisible
    imageButton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageButton2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageButton3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Using the above logic:

```
public void showAudio(View view) {
        if (!audioButtonClicked) {
            audioButtonClicked = true;
            eventButtonClicked = false;
            moreButtonClicked = false;
            audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_active);
            eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
            moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
        } else {
            audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_inactive);
            audioButtonClicked = false;
        }
}

public void showEvents(View view) {
        if(!eventButtonClicked ) {
            audioButtonClicked = false;
            eventButtonClicked = true;
            moreButtonClicked = false;
            audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_inactive);
            eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_active);
            moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
        } else {
           eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
           eventButtonClicked = false;
        }
}

public void showMore(View view) {
        if(!moreButtonClicked) {
            audioButtonClicked = false;
            eventButtonClicked = false;
            moreButtonClicked = true;
            audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_inactive);
            eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
            moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_active);

        } else {
            moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
            moreButtonClicked = false;
        }
}
```

This would show only when feature as enabled while other features as disabled. if any one of the features is enabled then the other two features get disabled but if only one feature is disabled then other are not changed.

Comment: i dont wanna make any button invisible. I just want a toggling feature to indicate when each button is active

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewSwitcher. put items in it and switch between them. only one is gonna show up. Below is an ex. with 2 view.

In layout_main.xml

```
<ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:text="next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

In the MainActivity.java

```
viewSwitcher =   (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
        text1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() != text1){
                       viewSwitcher.showPrevious(); 
                } else if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() != text2){
                    viewSwitcher.showNext();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
public void showAudio(View view) {

    audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_active);
    eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
    moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);

}

public void showEvents(View view) {

    audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_inactive);
    eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_active);
    moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);

}

public void showMore(View view) {


    audioWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_inactive);
    eventWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_inactive);
    moreWindowButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_active);

}
```